# UIbarButton Images not showing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I have created three UIBarButton Items and added them to a UINavigation controller.

The buttons work fine and show up if I set their images using this code:

```
[saveSearchButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Save Search"]];
```

I then wanted to make it so that when the button is tapped - it's image is changes to a "selected image"

Here is how I did that:

```
[butt setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"] forState:UIControlStateSelected style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

However, when I tap the button it's image doesn't change (Although, it's action method is called)

I tried setting its image for normal state like so:

```
[buttonOne setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

When I use the above code, the button is no longer visible. How can I change the button's selected image?

Here is the full code on how I add the buttons to the UINavigationBar

Creating them...

```
UIBarButtonItem *buttonOne = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:nil style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(buttonOnePressed)];
    UIBarButtonItem *buttonTwo = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:nil style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(buttonTwoPressed)];
    UIBarButtonItem *buttonThree = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:nil style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(buttonThreePressed)];
```

Adding to an array

```
NSArray *barButtonItems = @[buttonOne,buttonTwo,buttonThree,];
```

Add to the navigation item

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = barButtonItems;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];

[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonOnePressed:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                           initWithCustomView:button];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
```